# App with Firebase and Trigger.io - domain name

Tags: firebase

I have an app buit with Firebase I want to deploy using Trigger.io.
In the App I'm using the auth.login('twitter') function.
What domain name shall I put in the Auth setting of my app?

Thanks a lot  !

Comment: The domain the site's going to actually be available at.

Comment: There is not site - its an app deploy to smartphones!

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3012 may help.

Comment: sorry the confusion but this related to the domains Firebase allow you to be authenticated from which have to be declare in the Auth setting.

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] If you get a moment, please reach out to me directly (rob at firebase.com) and we can work through the configuration to make sure you get up and running properly. No domain configuration should be required for a hosted mobile app, but we'll need to make sure we can detect the environment and render the popup appropriately.

Comment: sent you an email - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on this thread in case anyone else is looking for the answer to this.

The OAuth-based authentication providers in Firebase Simple Login use pop-ups (via `window.open(...)` to initiate login flows, and `window.postMessage` to safely communicate between the two frames.

In order to enable these social, OAuth-based providers in Firebase Simple Login in the Trigger.io environment, there are a few steps:

- Ensure you're loading the latest Firebase Simple Login client from the Firebase CDN, at https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js.
- The Trigger.io environment support does not require an authorized domain configuration in Forge, but still will require that you configure your Facebook / Twitter / GitHub application to use the appropriate `https://auth.firebase.com/auth/...` redirect URL, as documented.
- Ensure that any required Trigger.io JavaScript libraries are included (the `forge` global variable should be set in your application - test with `console.log(forge)` in your client code).
- Lastly, and most important, the [Trigger.io Tabs Module](https://trigger.io/modules/tabs/current/docs/index.html) *must be enabled* in your application config.